# Создание списка твитов из jason в python. Ошибка JSONDecodeError: Extra data:

Tags: python

При попытке создания списка твитов из `json` получаю ошибку

> JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2829 (char 2828).

Мой код:

```
import twitter
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
authorization = twitter.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret)

import os

output_filename = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents", "Twitter", "python_tweets.json")
```

Далее создаю объект читающий твитты:

```
t = twitter.Twitter(auth=authorization)
```

Далее начинаю импорт твитов в выше-созданную директорию:

```
import json

with open(output_filename, 'a') as output_file:
    search_results = t.search.tweets(q="python", count=100)['statuses']
    for tweet in search_results:
        if 'text' in tweet:
            output_file.write(json.dumps(tweet))
            output_file.write("nn")
```

И здесь появляется ошибка:

```
import json
import os

# Input filename
input_filename = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents", "Twitter", "python_tweets.json")

tweets = []
with open(input_filename) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:
            continue
        tweets.append(json.loads(line))
```

Ошибка:

> ---
>
> JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         4         if len(line.strip()) == 0:
>         5             continue
>   ----> 6         tweets.append(json.loads(line))
>
> /Users/aleksandr/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>       352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
>       353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
>   --> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>       355     if cls is None:
>       356         cls = JSONDecoder
>
> /Users/aleksandr/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
>       340         end = _w(s, end).end()
>       341         if end != len(s):
>   --> 342             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>       343         return obj
>       344
>
> JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2829 (char 2828)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется надо изменить тут в записи:

```
if 'text' in tweet:
    output_file.write(json.dumps(tweet))
    output_file.write("\n")  # символ переноса строки, не понял чего у Вас "nn"
```

А Ваша ошибка скорее всего возникает по такому примеру:

```
>>> json.loads('{}')
{}
>>> json.loads('{}{}') # == json.loads(json.dumps({}) + json.dumps({}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... Тут текст ошибки
 ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 - line 1 column 5 (char 2 - 4)
```

Т.е. это надо изменить на что-то такое:

```
>>> dict1 = {}
>>> dict2 = {}
>>> json.dumps([dict1, dict2])
'[{}, {}]'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps([dict1, dict2]))
[{}, {}]
```

Но возможно, если Вы будете добавлять символ переноса строки а не "nn" все будет норм

Comment: Изменение символа переноса помогло.